# Which graphical tools can be used to display uni- or bivariate continuous data?

Tags: r, visualization, rstudio

There are 4 options to this multiple question,

- Scatterplots
- Conditional density plots
- Histograms
- Boxplots

I chose Scatterplots and Histograms but the answer is either wrong or not enough, I haven't seen anything about conditional density plots in my textbook and boxplots I'm not so sure. Tried googling it but there is no mention of boxplots.  I think I might have misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s asking you about [these](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49562/interpretation-of-conditional-density-plots) and [these](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_plot), both of which can visualise continuous data.

Comment: Oh so basically all 4 options are possible to be used to display either uni or bivariates? But aren't those for multivariates? Bi- only means it's for 2 variables. So those 2 don't fall into the category?

Comment: I would say conditional density plots bivariate continuous or one discrete and one continuous. Histogram one variable either discrete or continuous. Scatter plots, bivariate where at least one is continuous (both could in principle be discrete, but you’d probably end up with a degenerate scatter plot with lots of overlapping points), box plots univariate continuous.

Comment: So I asked the teacher, conditional density plots don't count. Only the other three.

Comment: Cool! Well done for checking with the teacher.